# Does graphql allow conditional execution of a step in a mutation?

Tags: graphql

Since you can have multiple steps run sequentially in a mutation, can you have a conditional if statement in graphql so that later steps only run if the result from a previous step meets a condition?

e.g.

```
 mutation upsertLogin($idToken: String!, $email: String!, $username: String!) {

    User(email: $email, username: $username) {
      id
    }

    // only do the next step if no id from from previous step

    createUser(email: $email, username: $username) {
      id
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, GraphQL doesn't support this kind of conditional execution. The only thing that is explicitly supported is throwing an error in one mutation in order to prevent the remainder of the mutations from running. This works because mutations run sequentially.

In theory you could implement the conditionals you mention by writing to and then reading from the context, which is shared between all resolvers, but I would not recommend doing so, because some implementations of GraphQL specifically declare the context to be immutable.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably have the resolver do this for you in case the user isn't found, however if folks try to login with wrong credentials then you run into the problem of making duplicative accounts and confused users.

I'd definitely encourage you to *not* try and implement this as it's not a great UX pattern. If the user isn't found, it could be for a number of reasons (wrong password, wrong email, inactive account...)

GraphQL does/could handle this in a semi-smart way, but this type of decisioning really should be left to your users.

Comment: in my use case this is triggered by an auth0 user creation so it would only fire in the case of a verified authentication event - and is used to sync the auth0 user info with a corresponding backend service.  Thus it would always only be one single reason rather than for user mistakes, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Considering that resolvers are a thing and mutations are promises, I can think of a few ways to do this.

1. Non GraphQL solution: Upsert at the DB level, I don't know your database technology, but plenty of them have an "Upsert" command" you can use.
2. Put a condition in the resolvers:

.

```
resolver(_, args) {
  if (myDB.find(args.username) === null) {
     createNewUser();
  }
```

3. Conditional promise chaining, client side

.

```
mutation1(credentials).then(result => {
  if (result) {
    mutation2.then();
  else {
    mutation3.then();
  }
}
```

Considering that this is Login, I would handle all of this server side for safety.